# Project no longer builds with android studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have updated my android studio, and also updated the gradle to 3.2.0.  Unfortunately when I try an build the project I get the following issues.

In build.gradle

```
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
```

turns red (at builder), and

```
new DefaultManifestParser(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
```

gets `could not find matching constructor for: com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser(java.io.File)`

Reverting to an earlier gradle fixes the issue, and I have deleted my .gradle cache.

Also I have verified the project builds with 3.1.2 gradle, and that there is a class in the downloaded gradle cache.

Comment: The error seems to suggest there are other possible constructors. Is there javadoc for that class anywhere?

Comment: Seems to be an internal class that you are using here. What's the goal of using it? Maybe there is another way.

Comment: the constructor of DefaultManifestParser changed and now it includes 2 more params 
```
public DefaultManifestParser(
            @NonNull File manifestFile,
            @NonNull BooleanSupplier canParseManifest,
            @Nullable EvalIssueReporter issueReporter) {
```

trying to figure out how to create the 2nd param - will post an answer once I manage to do that

Answer (score 3):

Constructor of DefaultManifestParser has changed as noted by [Noa Drach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2482564/noa-drach) in her answer so you have to provide additional parameters in it like this.

```
def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile, new BooleanSupplier() {
            @Override
            boolean getAsBoolean() {
                return true
            }
        }, null)
```

It Worked for me hope it works for you as well.

Comment: thanks for the tip. 
BTW I'm a woman and not a man, tried editing your post, but edit requires changing morecontent

Answer (score 1):

This is an initial place holder for an answer - I figured out that the constructor changed and now it has 2 additional parameters

    `/**
     * Builds instance of the parser, and parses the supplied file. The manifest is lazily parsed
     * and should typically only be parsed during the execution phase.
     *
     * @param manifestFile manifest to be parsed.
     * @param canParseManifest whether the manifest can currently be parsed.
     * @param issueReporter EvalIssueReporter
     */
    public DefaultManifestParser(
            @NonNull File manifestFile,
            @NonNull BooleanSupplier canParseManifest,
            @Nullable EvalIssueReporter issueReporter) {
...
    }`

however I'm still not sure how to produce the 2nd and 3rd params - any input will be appreciated.
(I know that i can pass null instead of the 3rd param, but knowing how to actually use it will be nice)

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite an answer, as it didn't found out whether the DefaultManifestParser is depricated or not.

I was using the manifest parser to get `versionName` and `versionCode` from the manifest.  This was a feature of my base project, and the build system had been complaining for a while.

In order to upgrade to 3.2 gradle, I changed my version from

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    versionName = manifestParser.getVersionName()
    versionCode = manifestParser.getVersionCode()
    ...
 }
```

To the following

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionName = "1.1.1.0"
    versionCode = 12
}
```

Deleting the versionName and versionCode following from my AndroidManifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.1.1.0">
```

to give me ....

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```